# How to Put values to Dynamically assigned Headings

Tags: php, mysql

I am working with this escenario:

```
Students Table
IDNUMBER
NAME
LEVEL
COURSE
SECTION


Exams Table
IDNUMBER
SUBJECT_ID 
SCORE


Student_Subject Table
SUBJECT_ID
LEVEL
COURSE
SECTION
```

SUBJECTID_1 SUBJECTID_2 SUBJECTID_3 ... Headings are dynamically generated based on Students Table LEVEL,COURSE and SECTION from Student_Subject Table then I gather the SUBJECT_ID from Student_Subject Table to get the SCORE from Exams Table.

Desired output

```
IDNUMBER NAME   SUBJECTID_1 SUBJECTID_2 SUBJECTID_3 ...
123456  JACK    6.5     8.5     9.0
```

I am able to get the headings,students listing and their scores but I get them in the wrong positions.

```
IDNUMBER NAME   SUBJECTID_1 SUBJECTID_2 SUBJECTID_3 ...
123456  JACK    9.0     8.5     6.5
```

Here is what I have so far.

```
 <?php
 include('../connect.php');

// Finds the Names

$sql="SELECT * FROM student WHERE course='$course' AND yearlevel='$year' AND section     ='$section' " ;

$result = mysql_query($sql);
echo $title.' SECCIÓN: '.'"'.$section.'"'; 
echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='1' id='resultTable'><tr><th>#</th><th>NIE</th>    <th>NOMBRE COMPLETO</th>";


// Finds subjects

$sql_subjects="SELECT subject FROM studentsubject WHERE course='$course' AND   level='$year' AND section ='$section'" ; 
$result_subjects = mysql_query($sql_subjects);
$s = '1';
while($subjects = mysql_fetch_array($result_subjects))
  {
  // Muestra los códigos de las materias.
  echo "<th style='text-align:center'>".$subjects['subject']."</th>";

  $s++;
  }


  echo "</tr>";
  $i='1';
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
   //Diplays  student info
    echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td style='text-align:center'>".$i."</td>";
  echo "<td>".$row['idnumber'];
  $student = $row['idnumber'];
  echo "<td>".$row['lname'].','.$row['fname']."</td>";

  $sql_grades="SELECT subject,score FROM exam WHERE idnum='$student' AND term='1'" ; 
  $result_grades = mysql_query($sql_grades);
  $g = '1';
  while($grades = mysql_fetch_array($result_grades))
  {
  // Displays the grades
  echo "<td style='text-align:center'>".$grades['score']."</td>";

   $g++;
  }

  echo "</tr>";
  $i++;
  }
 echo "</table>";
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you in advance for your response/support.

Hello everyone! After posting this question SO presented me with some suggested articles related to my question and after reading a few I was able to get the desire output for my project.
 Here it is what I came up with

```
// Finds students info
$sql="SELECT * FROM student WHERE course='$course' AND yearlevel='$year' AND section ='$section' " ;

$result = mysql_query($sql);
echo $title.' SECCIÓN: '.'"'.$section.'"'; 
echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='1' id='resultTable'><tr><th>#</th><th>NIE</th>   <th>NOMBRE COMPLETO</th>";


// Finds the  subjects

 $sql_subjects="SELECT subject FROM studentsubject WHERE course='$course' AND level='$year' AND section ='$section'" ; 
 $result_subjects = mysql_query($sql_subjects);
 $s = '1';
 $fsubject = array();
  while($subjects = mysql_fetch_array($result_subjects))
   {
   // Stores subject ID for later use.  
   $fsubject[]  = $subjects;
   // Writes Table Headings  for "subjects"
  echo "<th style='text-align:center'>".$subjects['subject']."</th>";

  $s++;
   }

 echo "</tr>";
 $i='1';
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
     //Writes students info
   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td style='text-align:center'>".$i."</td>";
   echo "<td>".$row['idnumber'];
   $student = $row['idnumber'];
   echo "<td>".$row['lname'].','.$row['fname']."</td>";


 //Finds subjects score based on subjectID

foreach($fsubject as $subject){
   //Stores subjectID 
    $test = $subject["subject"];
   // echo $test;

  // 
  // finds de exam scores based on SubjectID = $test in this case
     $sql_grades="SELECT subject,score FROM exam WHERE idnum='$student' AND term='1'    and subject='$test' "  ; 
   $result_grades = mysql_query($sql_grades);
   $g = '1';
   while($grades = mysql_fetch_array($result_grades))
   {

   // Displays scores
   echo "<td style='text-align:center'>".$grades['score']."</td>";

   $g++;
   }

   }

  echo "</tr>";
   $i++;
   }
 echo "</table>";
  ?>
```

Is there a better way to do this? I am learning , I don't know if this would cause a big load to the server.

Thank you for the suggestion of JOIN. I learnt a lot more with that but it was over the top for me and have no idea how to implement it in this case.

Comment: You should redesign your schema so you are not storing data in column names.

Answer (score 0):

Since your current code has the scores in reverse order, you could try using `ORDER BY score DESC` -

```
$sql_grades="SELECT subject,score FROM exam WHERE idnum='$student' AND term='1' ORDER BY score DESC" ;
```

But, you should learn how to use [`JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html), as your issue is that you have no relationship in your current code between the subject and score values.